# Knex migration not working when using migration API

Tags: node.js, migration, knex.js

I am new to knex migrations and for the past 2 days I have been struggling to get it working but nothing happen. I am trying to run my migrations programmatically using the `knex.migration` object.

First using the cli, I create a migration file in the migrations directory. Here is its content:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
   return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.createTable('users', function (table) {
            table.increments('id').primary();
            table.string('username');
            table.string('password');
            table.string('email');
            table.string('name');
            table.timestamp('date');
        }),
    ]);
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {

};
```

Then from my code I initialize the Knex object:

```
var knex = Knex({
        client:'sqlite3',
        connection:{
            filename: './knex.sqlite'
        }
    });
```

Then I execute the migration:

```
knex.migrate.latest().then(()=>{
        // console.log()
    }).catch(err =>{
        // 
    });
```

But absolutely nothing happens. My migration file is never executed and there is no error or warning message. So I don't know where to look at to start searching for the problem. When I look at my sqlite database, I can see that tables **knex_migrations**, **knex_migrations_lock** and **sqlite_sequence** have been created.

So what I am doing wrong here? Is there something I am missing?
Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: remove knex_migrations, knex_migrations_lock table from database and rerun. And console log the err on catch block.

Comment: How is your directory structure and knexfile? Could it be that you have your migrations in wrong folder?

Comment: Yes my migrations folder is not on the root of my project but in a subfolder. But I make sure to point to the right folder using the migrations.direction option in the config options. Also through debug, I stepped in the source code and I could see that Knex finds my folder and lists its content...But for some reasons it does not run the migrations...

Comment: There is no attribute `migrations.direction`.  If you have stepped that code in debugger you should be able to see there why migration files are not found. Anyways, with data given in this question there is no way to help you more. Try to write an example knex app and when you get that working, figure out what you do differently on your real app.

Comment: But there is **migrations.directory** attribute. Use it instead.

Answer (score 5):

There's no requirement to use the CLI tools. Sometimes it's not possible to use it due to its limitations and in this case it's indeed possible to use the migration API directly, like so:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    // Here goes the Knex config
});

const migrationConfig = {
    directory: __dirname + './migrations',
}

console.info('Running migrations in: ' + migrationConfig.directory);

knex.migrate.latest(migrationConfig).then(([batchNo, log]) => {
    if (!log.length) {
        console.info('Database is already up to date');
    } else {
        console.info('Ran migrations: ' + log.join(', '));
    }

    // Important to destroy the database, otherwise Node script won't exit
    // because Knex keeps open handles.
    knex.destroy();
});
```

There was two issues in the original question:

1. The migration directory was not specified - in this case Knex is not smart and will simply not do anything instead of throwing an error. Most likely the default used by Knex is not right so it's best to specify it.
2. `knex.destroy()` was missing. In this case, the script will never exit because Knex keeps open handles on the database, so it just looks like it's stuck doing nothing.

The above script also outputs more log info to see what's exactly happening.

Answer (score -1):

Knex migrations are supposed to run by `Knex CLI`，FYI: https://knexjs.org/#Migrations

As your code described, I found a strange issue:

knex.migrate is actually undefined, it's not a property of knex.