# How to run knex migrations with JavaScript instead of CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have created four postresql tables. I am using nodejs with knexjs as a query builder.

I can create and execute migrations with the command line without any problems. Now I want to run migrations via Javascript. How can I proceed with this?

Here is my code: -

```
module.exports.runDBMigrations = async () => {
    knex.schema.hasTable(USERS_DB_NAME).then(function (exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            //Execute migrations to create users tables
        }
    })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log("Error creating tables: ", e);
        })

    knex.schema.hasTable(POSTS_DB_NAME).then(function (exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            //Execute migrations to create posts tables
        }
    })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log("Error creating tables: ", e);
        })

    knex.schema.hasTable(LIKES_DB_NAME).then(function (exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            //Execute migrations to likes users tables
        }
    })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log("Error creating tables: ", e);
        })

    knex.schema.hasTable(FOLLOWERS_DB_NAME).then(function (exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            //Execute migrations to create followers tables
        }   
    })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log("Error creating tables: ", e);
        })

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304267/knex-migration-not-working-when-using-migration-api looks relevant

Comment: This one talks about latest file. I want to run previous files as well.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the docs -- latest is `Runs all migrations that have not yet been run.` Go to https://knexjs.org/ and check the migrations API (it's under all the details about how the migration CLI works).

Answer (score 1):

*Hi,*

Couple days I was sorrounding about how to run **migrations** and **seeds** when Server is starting.
Doing some researchs adn reading the Knex documentation, this is the solution what I reach to. Maybe this can help you.

---

### Stack

| lib | version |
| --- | --- |
| nodejs | *16.17.x* |
| nodemon | *^2.0.19* |
| npm | *8.19.x* |
| knex | *^2.3.0* |
| express | *^4.18.1* |
| pg | *^8.8.0* |
| postgreSQL | *14.5* |
| typescript | *^4.8.2* |

---

### Solution

**1.** Create a void function ***`runMigrations()`***. ***(I located in models/setup/)*** ***(you can name it as how you want)***

[image]

This function will have the knex singleton calling for running the migrations and the seeds.

**2.** Runn all the pending migrations calling the **knex** **migrate** ***`.latest()`*** method

[image]

This method is a promise, so you can capture the success creation or the error in case something goes wrong.

3. In this part, you can run all the seeds calling the **knex** **seed** ***`.run()`*** method. You can this method in the first callback

[image]

4. Call the migrations method in your index or server file. In my case Is ***`runMigrations()`*** method.

[image]

5. Restart your server, so you can check if everything works fine.

[image]

If you go to the terminal you can check response status. I add some log response, in order to know if everything working fine.

---

> Note
>
> I provoque an error so you can check the resutl if something were bad
> executing the migrations or seeds
>
> [image]

Maybe you'll find or your found others alternative of solution, but if you reach to fix the issue and added a different way; Please share it as a comment, so we can exchange knowledge and see a different way how to solve this issue.

Regards